# Do I need to use token_loader to implmement the "remember_me" feautre with Flask-login?

Tags: flask, flask-login

My current code seems to be working for "remember_me" to be working.

In `views.py` I have

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = SigninForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        user = User.query.filter_by(email = form.email.data.lower()).first()
        remember_me = form.remember_me.data
        if user and check_password_hash(user.pwdhash, form.password.data):
            login_user(user,  remember=remember_me)
            return redirect(url_for('index'))
        else:
            return redirect(url_for('login'))
    else:
        return render_template('login.html', form=form)
```

This is similar to Step 10 [here](https://blog.openshift.com/use-flask-login-to-add-user-authentication-to-your-python-application/). But I also see tutorials such as [this](http://thecircuitnerd.com/flask-login-tokens/) where a lot of work is done using `get_auth_token` and `token_loader`. Is one of these methods better? As I mentioned up top, my code seems to be working without these tokens, so what is going on?

Answer (score 0):

Your code is good enough and you don't need to use token_loader if you just want "remember me"